# Using error function in jquery/ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, error-handling

I'm working on a connection module in ajax/php using jquery. I need to throw an exception from php to ajax, to indicate whether email or password is false.

I searched all over the web for a way to use the 'error' function proposed by jquery's ajax. Found some solutions, none of them works.

Tried throwing a php exception : error function is not catching it ; tried avoiding using error function by sending json encoded data : no way of using it in success function...
Error function seems to only catch server errors, which is really NOT interesting.

Can anybody, please, help me find a way to communicate errors from php through ajax ?

Comment: what sort of error do u want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the request [statuscode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) in the php response to 4XX or 5XX. That will make you end up in the `error`/`fail` callback.

I dones't necessarily have to be a value in the list. For example, you can create your own:

```
StatusCode: 550
StatusText: "My Custom Error"
```

Which, if I recall correctly, would look like this in PHP:

```
header('HTTP/1.0 550 My Custom Error');
```

Finally, send the error details to the client to notify them of what went wrong. You can either place the info in the header, or serialize the exception using `json_encode()`

```
<?php

try {
    if (some_bad_condition) {
        throw new Exception('Test error', 123);
    }
    echo json_encode(array(
        'result' => 'vanilla!',
    ));
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo json_encode(array(
        'error' => array(
            'msg' => $e->getMessage(),
            'code' => $e->getCode(),
        ),
    ));
}

?>
```

Client side:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'page.php',
    data: { 'some_bad_condition': true }
}).done(function(data){

    console.log('success!', data);

}).fail(function(jqXhr){

    var errorObject = $.parseJSON(jqXhr.responseText);
    console.log('something went wrong:', errorObject);
    //jqXhr.status === 550
    //jqXhr.statusText === 'My Custom Error'

});
```

Don't forget to specify the correct mimetype in your PHP file. That way jQuery will know that it's a JSON response without you specifying it explicitly.

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Comment: @YonnTrimoreau See my update. You could make use of `success` + `error` callbacks if you prefer that.

Comment: did it 3 times ;) SO seems to have a problem accepting it, please be sure i'll retry until it works ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this plugin:

AJAXForm

[Get it here.](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)

The ajax handles the submission of the form, and if there is an error the error callback will be used.

I think I have previously used this. It is quite easy to use and check also if your return status code is correct in your php.

Comment: Thank you, but underestimating other members by sending them easy-to-use plugins and not teach them how to do it by themselves is quite insulting.